# What is maximum image size that IE Browser can open

Tags: internet-explorer

I am trying to open a png image file of 300MB(resolution around 19848*20238 px) image size , but it is not opening.

Same image is perfectly opening in Chrome browser.

I also tried to directly browse and open the image file, but IE but it did not open . But same image got opened in Chrome.

For 150 MB size image was loading partially in IE.

I also tried for some other size images like  350MB and above , but none of them opened in IE but same got opened in Chrome.

Image content is correct.

It seems some IE browser issue or limitation.

Comment: Had anyone faced any similar issue ever.